# How to reserve a file descriptor?

Tags: c, debugging, posix, file-descriptor

I'm writing a curses-based program. In order to make it simpler for me to find errors in this program, I would like to produce debug output. Due to the program already displaying a user interface on the terminal, I cannot put debugging output there.

Instead, I plan to write debugging output to file descriptor 3 unconditionally. You can invoke the program as `program 3>/dev/ttyX` with `/dev/ttyX` being a different teletype to see the debugging output. When file descriptor 3 is not opened, write calls fail with `EBADF`, which I ignore like all errors when writing debugging output.

A problem occurs when I open another file and no debugging output has been requested (i.e. file descriptor 3 has not been opened). In this case, the newly opened file might receive file descriptor 3, causing debugging output to randomly corrupt a file I just opened. This is a bad thing. How can I avoid this? Is there a portable way to mark a file descriptor as “reserved” or such?

Here are a couple of ideas I had and their problems:

- I could open `/dev/null` or a temporary file to file descriptor 3 (e.g. by means of `dup2()`) before opening any other file. This works but I'm not sure if I can assume this to always succeed as opening `/dev/null` may not succeed.
- I could test if file descriptor 3 is open and not write debugging output if it isn't. This is problematic when I'm attempting to restart the program by calling `exec` as a different file descriptor might have been opened (and not closed) prior to the `exec` call. I could intentionally close file descriptor 3 before calling `exec` when it has not been opened for debugging, but this feels really uggly.

Comment: Why does it have to be fd 3? Why does it have to be invoked with a explicit descriptor from the shell? The usual solution is to handle this inside your application. Pass an additional opt like --debug-file=FILE to your application, open that file and store the descriptor returned by open() internally to use as debug output.

Comment: @Juliano Because that's easier than implementing an extra command line option and also easier to use (file descriptor has to be specified only once instead of twice).

Comment: @FUZxxl *Because that's easier than implementing an extra command line option and also easier to use*  It sure doesn't appear to be easier.  What happens if something else winds up with 3 as its file descriptor?

Comment: @AndrewHenle If you would please read the question before commenting. I discuss this scenario there and it's in fact the core of the problem I experience.

Comment: Option 1 is fine, at least, on POSIX-compliant systems. POSIX says that lowest file descriptor available is assigned for `open(2)` call.

Comment: `...but this feels really ugly.` Given that the whole solution is incredibly ugly and brittle, I wouldn't worry too much about it.

Comment: BTW, you could send debugging output to a real file (don't forget to `fflush` it appropriately!), and run `tail -f yourdebugfile` in some *other* terminal

Comment: @FUZxxl - I don't see how setting a requirement for a file descriptor with a specific value makes things easier.  Just use a global `int` as your debug file descriptor.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch That is one of the possibilities with the use-fd3-approach. It's very flexible. (The caller needs to invoke the program like this: `program 3>yourdebugfile`).

Comment: @AndrewHenle It's easier for the user who doesn't has to specify extra options to get debugging output.

Comment: Since this is for debugging, you could `LD_PRELOAD` a shared library and `dup2` your file descriptors before anything to reserve 3.

Comment: @dashesy Note that I'm the author of this program, so I could also do this directly in the program itself if it would help at all (which it does not). Please read the question and the discussion before making suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You claim you can't guarantee you can open `/dev/null` successfully, which is a little strange, but let's run with it. You should be able to use `socketpair()` to get a pair of FDs. You can then set the write end of the pair non-blocking, and `dup2` it. You claim you are already ignoring errors on writes to this FD, so the data going in the bit-bucket won't bother you. You can of course close the other end of the socketpair.

Comment: That's an approach that could work. I'm worried about `/dev/null` as the application should also work when the system is in a non-functional state (e.g. `/dev` isn't mounted yet).

Comment: @FUZxxl, Actually playing around with booting systems a good while ago I do remember bad things happened when applications couldn't access `/dev/null` (I think it was a permission issue), so I sympathise.

Comment: @FUZxxl If `/dev` hasn't been mounted yet, how do you plan to use the shell to redirect your debug output to `/dev/ttyX`? You should clarify the exact circumstances under your application is supposed to work in the question, not adding more "but this won't work because..." comments after each answer.

Comment: @biziclop In this situation debugging doesn't need to work but my application needs to work. If the solution required to have `/dev/null` when debugging is enabled, that would be fine.

Answer (score 4):

Why use fd 3? Why not use fd 2 (stderr)? It already has a well-defined "I am logging of some sorts" meaning, is always (not true, but sufficiently true...) and you can redirect it before starting your binary, to get the logs where you want.

Another option would be to log messages to syslog, using the LOG_DEBUG level. This entails calling `syslog()` instead of a normal write function, but that's simply making the logging more explicit.

A simple way of checking if stderr has been redirected or is still pointing at the terminal is by using the `isatty` function (example code below):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void) {
  if (isatty(2)) {
    printf("stderr is not redirected.\n");
  } else {
    printf("stderr seems to be redirected.\n");
  }
}
```

Comment: Please read about how curses works. Hint: It uses file descriptor 2 for the TUI stuff if available. Yes, I could fight against how curses work but this would impede the primary function and make my program suddenly behave differently from all other curses applications, which is a bad thing. `syslog()` is global and not very suitable for my situation.

Comment: @FUZxxl Last I programmed ncurses applications, fd2 was perfectly free for use, this was however close to 15 years ago. If you'd included *why* you were unable to use fd2, I would not have suggested it. My suggestion for syslog still stands.

Comment: I wrote why I couldn't use fd2: it goes to the terminal by default so I either need to provide a flag to turn on debug output (which I don't want) or I have to find another way to find out if stderror has been redirected or not (which may not be easy to do correctly).

Answer (score 2):

In the very beginning of your program, open `/dev/null` and then assign it to file descriptor 3:

```
 int fd = open ("/dev/null", O_WRONLY);
 dup2(fd, 3);
```

This way, file descriptor 3 won't be taken.

Then, if needed, reuse `dup2()` to assign file descriptor 3 to your debugging output.

Comment: I know about `dup2`. How does this solve my problem?

Comment: @FUZxxl If FD 3 is not open at start up, open "/dev/null" and use dup2 to ensure it uses FD 3 (if the open call did not already return FD 3)

Comment: @JonasWielicki That's one of the approaches I discuss in the question. It's problematic because I'm not sure if I can assume that I can open `/dev/null` successfully.

Comment: @FUZxxl Ah, I assumed that in your question, the difficulty you described was related to being sure that it is assigned FD 3. Well, you could always dup2 stdin (or anything else opened only for reading). That will also give you EBADF (when writing to it).

Comment: @JonasWielicki In an application running on a terminal, `stdin` usually refers to the same file description as `stdout` and `stderr`, i.e. the terminal. Writing to `stdin` would mess up the terminal just as good as writing to `stderr`.

Comment: Check the new answer.

Comment: @Claudio Thank you for spelling out the exact approach I already discussed in the question. Please read the entire question before writing an answer I already discuss in it. You will find that the problem with this approach is that I'm not sure if I can assume that `/dev/null` exists and that opening it is going to succeed.

Comment: @FUZxxl `/dev/null` is one of the files that POSIX requires.

Answer (score 1):

Don't focus on a specific file descriptor value - you can't control it in a portable manner anyway.  If you can control it at all.  But you can use an environment variable to control debug output to a file:

```
int debugFD = getDebugFD();

...

int getDebugFD()
{
    const char *debugFile = getenv( "DEBUG_FILE" );
    if ( NULL == debugFile )
    {
        return( -1 );
    }

    int fd = open( debugFile, O_CREAT | O_APPEND | O_WRONLY, 0644 );
    // error checking can be here

    return( fd );
}
```

Now you can write your debug output to `debugFD`.  I assume you know enough to make sure `debugFD` is visible where you need it, and also how to make sure it's initialized before trying to use it.

If you don't pass a `DEBUG_FILE` envval, you get an invalid file descriptor and your debug calls fail - presumably silently.

Comment: Of course you can control a specific file descriptor value portably: Just execute the program with an appropriate shell redirection like `3>debug_file`. Perfectly portable, simple, and fine.

Comment: @FUZxxl *Of course you can control a specific file descriptor value portably: Just execute the program with an appropriate shell redirection like 3>debug_file. Perfectly portable, simple, and fine.*  Then why did you ask?  Because you can't control it - if you don't set it that way, something else will use it - hence you do **not**  have control over file descriptor 3 - you can *use* it.  You **can't** *control* it.

Comment: Again: If file descriptor 3 is open when my program starts, I want to write debugging output to it. If not, I do not want to do that. The semantics I desire are simple and clear.

Comment: @FUZxxl *The semantics I desire are simple and clear.*  If that were true, you'd be able to write simple and clear code to implement what you're trying to do.

Comment: That conclusion is incorrect. Many programs have simple and clear semantics that are incredibly hard to implement correctly, think many of the UNIX utilities like the korn shell. Simplicity of specification does not imply simplicity of implementation and vice versa.

Comment: @FUZxxl You are attempting to *control* something you can only *use* if it's available - file descriptor 3.  You need another solution - or you can keep telling everyone else how wrong they all are.

Comment: Which is why I am asking this question: How can I make sure nobody else uses file descriptor 3. If your answer is “that's not possible” and you are sufficiently sure of that,  then please go ahead and post that as an answer. “Your approach is stupid” is not a productive answer to this question, regardless of how politely it is written.

Comment: @FUZxxl *please go ahead and post that as an answer.*  Scroll up a few inches -  *Don't focus on a specific file descriptor value - you can't control it in a portable manner anyway. If you can control it at all.*

Comment: That's not “that's not possible.” Also, I refuted your point. You can control what file is associated with a file descriptor (e.g. by means of `dup2`), and my question concerns whether it is possible to reserve a file descriptor for whatever purpose. If the answer to that specific question is “that's impossible” and you are sufficiently sure, that please write exactly that. Your answer is unsure (“If you can control it at all”), instead suggesting me to try something else (not productive).

Comment: @FUZxxl *You can control what file is associated with a file descriptor (e.g. by means of `dup2`)*  No, that's *using* it - and rather forced at that as you break whatever *was* using it prior to your `dup2` call.  You continue to conflate *using* something with *control*.  Calling me names and speciously claiming *I refuted your point* doesn't change the fact that **YOU** are struggling with this because you don't understand the difference between *use* and *control*.  Had you understood what you were trying to do you wouldn't have had to ask your question.